# Static folder in NodeJs

Tags: node.js, webpack

I suppose my question is basic but I'm new to Node.js infrastructure and feel very confused.

I have a simple web-site where all my js files are bundled by webpack into `bundle.js` that is available by `/static/bundle.js` path (according to webpack configuration).

But now I have another folder with static data in the root of my project and I want to make it publicly available by `/static2/...` address. How can I do this? Who is responsible for that (webpack, nodejs, etc.)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use express - you can take a look here:

http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

For example:

```
app.use(express.static('public'));
```